# API response not being saved to a useState()

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, fetch-api

I'm working on a react native weather app project. I am using openWeatherMapAPI and opencagedata for geolocation. First, Im calling the `getGeo()` function that takes in the city and stores the lat and lon from the API. Next, to get the actual weather data, I am calling the `getWeatherData()` function that makes the request to the API that uses the lat and lon for the location and stores the JSON data in the `weatherData` `useState()`.

This all seems like it should work, but it does not. I have the functions run once a button is pressed `getGeo() --> getWeatherData()`, but I end up needing to press the button 3 times to get any data to be saved to the `weatherData`.

CODE:

```
  function getGeo(){
    fetch(`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${city}&key=${geoApi}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        setGeoData(JSON.stringify(data));
        setLat(data.results[0].geometry.lat)
        setLon(data.results[0].geometry.lng)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors that occur
        alert(error);
    });
  }

  function getWeatherData() {
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&exclude=minutely&appid=${weatherApi}&units=metric`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        setWeatherData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));   
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors that occur
        alert(error);
    });

    console.log(weatherData)
    setShowData(true);

  }

  
  function onPress() {
    // hide the keyboard
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    // get the lat and lon
    getGeo();
    // get the weather data 
    getWeatherData()

    }
```

To fix my problem, I tried to use `async and await` functions thinking the code was moving on before the weather API could respond to the request. when I did this I didn't solve my problem the same result happened as before. (Needing to press the button 3 times for data to be entered into the `weatherData useState`)

I have also tried to use promises while trying to get the response from the API call with no different result.

this is the output I get to the console while pressing the button

`LOG  undefined`

`LOG  {"cod": "400", "message": "Nothing to geocode"}`

`LOG  {"current": {"clouds": 35......`

is there anything else I can try to fix this issue?

Comment: `.then((data) => { setGeoData(JSON.stringify(data));         setLat(data.results[0].geometry.lat);  setLon(data.results[0].geometry.lng); getWeatherData();   })`